# What is the best way for save and load setting in my program?

Tags: c#, application-settings

I have build  a C# program.

I need to keep setting of my program and I need to load them when the program load

(I know to do it with simple text file....but i don't have good documentation of the variable)

what is the best way to do it ?

Can I get any sample ?

Comment: Voted to close as duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/744746/best-way-to-save-per-user-options-in-c

Answer (score 7):

In your solution, if you right click on the project and click on properties, there's a settings tab. You can define the settings you want to track and their types there and then access them through code, like this:

```
Properties.Settings.Default.SettingName = "Test Value";
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

And then on load:

```
textBox.Text = Properties.Settings.Default.SettingName;
```

Answer (score 7):

I'd argue that just hinting towards `appSettings` doesn't really cover the topic, as there is more advanced and eventually easier to use stuff readily available. Given that this question might be a

#### Duplicate

> [Best way to save per user options in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/744746/best-way-to-save-per-user-options-in-c)

Please note that the MSDN link provided there ([User settings in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869.aspx)) covers both user and application scoped settings on an easy to grasp introductory level and basically elaborates on the correct example [provided by jasonh already](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1121427/what-is-the-best-way-for-save-and-load-setting-in-my-program/1121562#1121562).

For a much deeper coverage of these topics (assuming you are using Windows Forms or WPF with Visual Studio) I'd recommend to look into [Application Settings for Windows Forms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0zszyc6e.aspx).

Answer (score 6):

Use [appSettings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869%28VS.80%29.aspx) (that's the MSDN link, here's more of [a quick overview](http://www.thescarms.com/dotnet/AppSettings.aspx)).

Answer (score 0):

How about storing the settings in XML?

Reading and writing them is [pretty easy](http://www.dotnetjohn.com/articles.aspx?articleid=173).