# Updating .config file with data from the user

Tags: c#, app-config, appsettings

I am trying to save some settings to the appSettings section of my configuration file so I may use the data to carry out the processes of the program. On the click of a button I want the data coming from the user to be saved in the config file. The code I am using is:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

            System.Configuration.Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

            config.AppSettings.Settings["key1"].Value = "value1";
            config.AppSettings.Settings["key2"].Value = "value2";

            config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
            ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings");
```

}

Before the code is executed my app.config file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
  </configSections>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="roshane" value=""/>
    <add key="email" value=""/>
    <add key="super" value=""/>
    <add key="phone" value=""/>
  </appSettings>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="AutoReportEmailerConnectionString"
        connectionString="Data Source=roshane\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=ICR_v5.0;Integrated Security=True"
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5"/>
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

After the code is execute the programName.exe.config file is the same as the app.config. Is there something I am missing why the values are not being added to the programName.exe.config file?

Comment: A borderline duplicate. Suggest that you absorb the info in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4514945/14357) and reconsider your question.

Comment: where you use "key1" and "key2" you should use "roshane" or "email".....

Comment: do you want to add values or modify existing ones?

Answer (score 0):

config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified) works only when you modify an exisint key in other words a key that was in the web config before if you need to actually add key values to the web config just call config.Save() with no parameters

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add new Key to config file, need to add it first in Settings collection:

```
config.AppSettings.Settings.Add("Key", "Value");
```

Then call Save method.

Comment: yes i know its the title using updating word but at the end OP says added so your probably right.