# Where can i place common user data other than LOCALMACHINE -Registry without Administrative Rights

Tags: c#, .net, windows, registration, user-data

In Windows other than the registry -localmachine where can I place common user data that could be accessed by all users.

i need to do this **without** requesting elevation of **admin** rights

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4514929/save-application-preferences-registry-file

Comment: So long as the data is not _too large_, you may want to consider _Isolated Storage_

Comment: @Micky its just some licensing data.I think there is no way to write to `local machine` registry other than creating a new program with admin rights.My app does not require admin rights now.

Comment: That's the nice thing about Isolated Storage, it gives you a unified and abstracted way to write to _user; machine; assembly; app_ or combination there-off so that a user or groups of users can read/write data without running into security hickups or really caring _where_ it will be stored.  It just works :)

Comment: @Micky Does it work without Admin rights?

Comment: @techno yes. It was designed for that, particularly with ClickOnce where apps are installed _without_ admin rights

Comment: @Micky Can you post some sample as the answer?

Comment: @techno See my answer below'

Comment: @HarryJohnston Well no, _user_ can actually mean a "user" or machine.   e.g. `IsolatedStorageFile.GetMachineStoreForApplication()`

Answer (score 3):

You can store it in the Application data folder. which you can get from Envorinment:

```
var appDataFolder = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonDocuments);
```

To determine if you can access the folder without admin right, run Visual Studio, without admin rights, and see if this code executes successfully.

```
   class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var folder = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonDocuments);
            var file = Path.Combine(folder, "testfile.txt");

            File.WriteAllText(file, " Test Settings");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

Comment: But i read somwhere on SO that writing to this folder require admin rights

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10507233/how-to-write-to-the-common-application-data-folder

Comment: Aha, true. `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonDocuments);` does not require admin rights.

Comment: where is this folder located?

Comment: It depends on operating system version. It can be `C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Documents` or `C:\Users\Public`. It corresponds to `%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\Documents`

Comment: when entering the path in explorer i get `access denied` error

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Answer (score 1):

No such location is available by default. Regular (*i.e.*, non-administrative users) do not have the requisite privileges to mess with system files or files that belong to other users—that would be a security issue. As such, they would not be able to write to a "common" directory.

If you need all users to be able to write to some type of common area, you need to set it up yourself. Generally, this is done by an installer application. The installer application will need to request elevation so that it has administrative privileges in order to write to restricted folders and alter security rights. If you're using a standard installer utility, then this is usually a built-in feature. If you're writing your own, you arrange for it to have administrative privileges by embedding a manifest with `level` set to `requireElevation` (search Stack Overflow for details).

The installer it will create a sub-directory of the common application data folder (the enumerated value `Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData` in the .NET world) for your application's use. By default, of course, that sub-directory will inherit the restrictions of its parent folder, so the installer will also need to explicitly set the ACL (access control list) on that sub-directory to grant all users write access. This can be done in the .NET Framework using the [Directory.SetAccessControl method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.setaccesscontrol.aspx).

Then, after installation is complete, administrative privileges will *not* be required to run your application. The application can just save into its own sub-directory of the common application data folder, which its installer has ensured that all users have read/write access to.

Comment: Well, the sort order of the answers changes, so I'm not sure which answer you're talking about. Jvanrhyn's answer is correct insofar as it goes. You will want to create a subdirectory of a common folder like `SpecialFolder.CommonDocuments`, but you can't write there without administrative privileges. So that's why you need to the installer dance. Or elevate on-demand the first time your application runs. If you're talking about Micky's answer, regarding isolated storage, I really have no idea how that works.