# Add new persistent user setting at runtime

Tags: c#, settings

I have a software that should run with non-admin privileges (can't write to app.config).

I'm creating a new user setting:

```
var property = new SettingsProperty(key)
{
    DefaultValue = val,
    IsReadOnly = false,
    PropertyType = typeof(T),
    Provider = Settings.Default.Providers["LocalFileSettingsProvider"]
};
property.Attributes.Add(typeof(UserScopedSettingAttribute), new UserScopedSettingAttribute());
Settings.Default.Properties.Add(property);
Settings.Default.Reload();
```

and it saves it for the session, but not shown at the next software load.

How can I create an entirely new user setting that will be available at next run?

Comment: [Save application preferences… registry/file?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4514945/14357)

Comment: It can't be done in the user settings? 
Many of my settings are not new, and will work and be updated using user settings, so I prefer to have the runtime-created ones there as well

Comment: So [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397750.aspx) page is the reference for this sort of thing. Did you work through it? (in particular "How To: Write User Settings at Run Time with C#")

Comment: I looked at this page,
but it says how to update an existing value. the code above is creating a new one, but it is lost the next time I load the program. 
BTW - the value still exist in the user settings file in appdata, but I can't reach it unless it is defined at runtime

Comment: Maybe it would be better to maintain your own settings file in `Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData),"yourappname")` as a JSON or XML file?

Comment: Thanks, that is probably what I'll do :)