# C# Handling User Settings

Tags: c#, storage, configuration-files

First of all, I'm not looking for some piece of code (that will help, but I want to learn).

I'm trying to make an email program. Not for distribution, just for learning. I've already got the encryption ready. What I want to be able to do now is add users and store their settings somewhere. That will include the username, email, and password (and some other small stuff, but this is the main stuff).

What do you guys think that is the best way to store these settings so I can call them in the program?

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26369/what-is-the-best-way-to-store-user-settings-for-a-net-application

Comment: Isolated storage may be what you're looking for http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.isolatedstorage.aspx

Comment: You should work with a DB, obviously. If it is your first time, you can use MSAccess instead of an actual data base. There is also MySql which is great. Read those up on google.

Comment: [Duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/744746/best-way-to-save-per-user-options-in-c-sharp)

Comment: @BryanCrosby, i would like to, but i've i ask something, and no suitable answers where given, then i don't pick up random an answer and upvote that one...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After taking a look at the comment that where given, these links helped me:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0zszyc6e

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.isolatedstorage.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I recently made my own and i used serialization. Define a user witch has the persons name and info and settings. Save all the user objects in a xml file using serialization. Its pretty easy, just read it in and add them to an array to have all the users. Might want a separate xml file for the user name and passwords dictionary.

Here is a good link for serialization in case you need it:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms233843.aspx

Comment: Thank for your thoughts. I've thought about something like that. That will make an own file (with it's own type) and procces the data to and from it. Just started working on the class :-D