# How to load user settings and values

Tags: c#, .net, settings

What is the best way of loading many user settings at once. For example my application has many user settings like :

`settingCapitalizeStrings bool user true`

then in my `FormOptions_Load` I need to loop through all settings and values like :

```
private void FormOptions_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(s.settingCapitalizeStrings == true)
    {
       capitalizeStringsCheckBox.Checked = true;
    }
    // and many many more
}
```

and then handle every `CheckBox_CheckedChanged`

Is there better solution ? Can I bind user settings or something like that?

Comment: Are you not using the config file features build into .net?

Comment: What is it that you exactly want to acheive with this? Depending on your needs you can either use the config file as suggested by @hatchet r you could possibly create an extension method that takes a couple of parameters and use that?

Comment: Seems like he wants a per user setting, not a global setting.  App/web.config would only work if ALL users wanted the setting to be the same.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/744746/best-way-to-save-per-user-options-in-c-sharp and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/909688/what-is-the-difference-between-app-config-file-and-xyz-settings-file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest to use [Application Settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k4s6c3a0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

1. Select checkbox in designer
2. Go to properties and select *(ApplicationSettins)*
3. Go to *Checked*, click on its value and select *new*
4. Add new application setting scoped to user

[image]

That will generate code which loads setting from file and adds binding to `Checked` property of checkbox (that will load property value from settings file during form creation and update settings file when it checkbox `Checked` property value will be changed):

```
this.capitalizeStringsCheckBox.Checked = global::WindowsFormsApplication.Properties.Settings.Default.CapitalizeStrings;
this.capitalizeStringsCheckBox.DataBindings.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.Binding("Checked", global::WindowsFormsApplication.Properties.Settings.Default, "CapitalizeStrings", true, System.Windows.Forms.DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged));
```

Comment: This is it. Thanks. I'm using `DevExpress CheckEdit` so I could not find that. With `native CheckBox` everything works well.

Comment: When using `DevExpress CheckEdit` bind `EditValue` property to application setting.

Answer (score 1):

Try to have a look at Configuration, and put everything in app.config:
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configuration(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configuration%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Also,

```
private void FormOptions_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    capitalizeStringsCheckBox.Checked = s.settingCapitalizeStrings;
}
```

is much more elegant.